# Overlaying a videoView over another videoView using Relative Layout and button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am fairly new to Android Studio and trying out a project where based on a click event the videoView  (2 videos) changes from vid1 to vid2 vid2 to vid1 and so on and both are simultaneously playing and are of the same length. When I use the built-in function bringToFront(), the videos are not swapping and I am only able to see the first video.

```
Button button;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        vd1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView6);
        vd1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.venapp/" + R.raw.first));
        vd1.start();
        vd1.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                vd1.start();
            }
        });

        vd2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView5);
        vd2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.venapp/" + R.raw.second));
        vd2.start();
        vd2.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                vd2.start();
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (counter % 2 == 0) { // even # of click
                    counter++;
                    vd2.bringToFront();
                }
                else if (counter % 2 != 0) { // odd # of click
                    counter++;
                    vd1.bringToFront();
                }
            }
        });
```

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `bringToFront()`, you can set the visibility of the entire view by using `setVisibility()` with a parameter of `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE`.

To achieve the effect you want, you can use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)

Comment: When adding those additions of ```setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)``` and ```setVisibility(View.GONE)``` The transition works fine from vid1 to vid2  but vid2 back to vid1 and thereon after is just a black screen in the layout/view.

Comment: Looks like when you use GONE or INVISIBLE the video is being stopped thus causing the black screen on the second iteration when switching from vid2 to vid1 (since vid1 was previously set to invisible). Any alternate solutions or fix to this issue will be appreciated.